# Does the jclouds s3 API support "307 temporary redirect" in response to a PUT with header Expect: 100-continue?

Tags: jclouds

Results in our testing suggest the redirect is not supported, although other clients e.g. curl & s3cmd do.  Redirect should be supported per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTRedirect.html#RESTRedirect100Continue.  Pointers confirming support or lack of support in jclouds source would be of value.

Comment: Can you please share some code snippets what you are doing and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[S3RedirectionRetryHandler](https://github.com/apache/jclouds/blob/624367dfbf4f6b86bc53aa2a7ac14c8db02533f3/apis/s3/src/main/java/org/jclouds/s3/handlers/S3RedirectionRetryHandler.java#L50)  handles 301 and 307.

jclouds support the 307 redirect. All 3xx response
codes are intercepted [here](https://github.com/apache/jclouds/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/http/handlers/DelegatingRetryHandler.java#L64-L65), then processed, by default (unless a
provider defines its own redirection retry handler) [here](https://github.com/apache/jclouds/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/http/handlers/RedirectionRetryHandler.java#L59).